# Switching List View to Grid View in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin is quite new for me. So sorry to be so inexperienced. I've to create List like Product list of Amazon where there is a toggle button to display products from vertical listing to 2 column listing (Grid).

In android I've implemented this by using the feature of Recycler view where we can set the orientation of layout at run time.

I'd hard time trying to find out how can I achieve this in Xamarin forms so it can work for both Android & iOS.

Please give your inputs if you have done something like this in Xamarin.

Comment: Have you tried the Xamarin Forms ListView? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/. There is even a 'performance' section in the Xamarin Forms Docs for enabling caching (like the reclycling feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a Grid, X.Forms built-in List is not the best one. But you can use this one:

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

It's fantastic for the Grid display you're looking for. Very flexible and well documented.

Xamarin.Forms [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) is pretty solid, so you won't have any problems working with her

For performance issues use this [List View Performance](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/)

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

i hope that work.. 
put in your controller class

```
public override void DidRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        // past inside your code with orientation condition
        //UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation to get orientation  


    }
```